# How to cancel jobs on Slurm with job ID(job number) bigger than a certain number?

Tags: command-line, slurm

I have submitted 800 jobs on Slurm. I want to cancel those jobs that have job ID/number bigger than a number(since there is a mistake in them). I don't want to cancel all my jobs because some are running and some that are in the queue are correct.

Answer (score 27):

It is not strictly answering how to cancel jobs greater that a given number, but it would work for the problem @mona-jalilvand was trying to solve : cancel jobs in a range as described [here](https://safariding.wordpress.com/2017/03/19/scancel-for-a-job-range-with-bash/)

```
scancel  {1000..1050}
```

Much simpler then getting into bash scripting... worked well for me.

Comment: I brute-forced my way out by running `scancel {70000-71000}` to cancel "all" jobs with id bigger than 70000. You deserve best prize for thinking out of the box, saved me an hour of my time thanks!

Comment: Thanks @mugen for your kind words! Happy it could have save you some time :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `squeue` to get a list of all jobs belonging to you, then loop over that list and cancel each job that matches your criterion (job id greater than X) with `scancel`.

`squeue` has very flexible output options, with its `-o` aka `--format` option you can tell it to print exactly what you want.  In this case, we only want the job number.  According to `man squeue`, that is `%i` in the format string:

> **%i** Job or job step id.
>
> In the case of job arrays, the job ID
>   format will be of the  form  "_".   By
>   default, the job array index field size will be limited to
>   64 bytes.  Use the environment  variable  SLURM_BITSTR_LEN
>   to  specify  larger  field sizes.  (Valid for jobs and job
>   steps) In the case of heterogeneous job  allocations,  the
>   job  ID  format  will be of the form "#+#" where the first
>   number is the "heterogeneous job leader"  and  the  second
>   number  the  zero  origin offset for each component of the
>   job.

The following sh script uses that:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "Minimum Job Number argument is required.  Run as '$0 jobnum'"
    exit 1
fi

minjobnum="$1"

myself="$(id -u -n)"

for j in $(squeue --user="$myself" --noheader --format='%i') ; do
  if [ "$j" -gt "$minjobnum" ] ; then
    scancel "$j"
  fi
done
```

Save it as, e.g., `cancel-jobs.sh`, make it executable with `chmod +x cancel-jobs.sh`, and run it as `./cancel-jobs.sh 50000` to cancel all your jobs with job ids greater than 50,000.

If you want it to cancel job numbers greater than or equal to the minimum job number, change the `-gt` to `-ge`.

---

One minor optimisation is to not cancel each job individually, but to build up a list of matching job numbers and then cancel them all with one invocation of `scancel`.

For example, using a bash array to hold the job numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a jobs=()

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
    echo "Minimum Job Number argument is required.  Run as '$0 jobnum'"
    exit 1
fi

minjobnum="$1"

myself="$(id -u -n)"

for j in $(squeue --user="$myself" --noheader --format='%i') ; do
  if [ "$j" -gt "$minjobnum" ] ; then
    jobs+=($j)
  fi
done

scancel "${jobs[@]}"
```

This does the same thing as the first script, but slightly more efficiently.

Comment: note: your username may, and probably is, already be in a variable in your shell, probably called `$USER`.  I wrote the script to work whether that variable exists or not - if it does exist, you don't need the `$myself` variable.  Delete the `myself="$(id -u -n)"` line and change `$myself` to `$USER` on the for loop line that runs `squeue`.

Answer (score 2):

I often use

```
squeue -u $user | sort
```

to sort the queue on job ID. In this case you have the largest job ID at the bottom of the screen, say 22222. If you find that 11111 is the first bad one you can cancel the range with

```
scancel {11111..22222}
```

where `{}` is expanded by the shell (try `echo {3..11..2}` for example).